# How would I import an installed package that has a hyphen in the package name in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, package

The package I'm trying to import is nflgame-redux==2.0.1a1

I'd write:

```py
import nflgame-redux==2.0.1a1
```

Error I get is:

File "", line 1
    import nflgame-redux==2.0.1a1
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: just do `import nflgame`

Comment: nflgame is only supported by Python 2, and I'm running 3